# Add features to the map in OpenLayers 5

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-5

I have a following code in HTML

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Vector Style Examples</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.1.3/css/ol.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Teko" rel="stylesheet"> 
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.1.3/build/ol.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
<script>
var map = new ol.Map({
    view: new ol.View({center: ol.proj.transform([16.9278, 52.4044], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'), zoom:12}),
    layers: [new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
    })],
    target:'map'
});

var marker = new ol.Feature({
    geometry: new ol.geometry.point(ol.proj.transform([16.9071388, 52.4901917], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')),
});

var markers = new ol.source.Vector({
    features: [marker]
});

var markerVectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: markers,
});
map.addLayer(markerVectorLayer);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

It's not displaying any points, only the map. In the console, I get the error "ol.geom.point is not a constructor". This code is mostly based on this tutorial
https://medium.com/attentive-ai/working-with-openlayers-4-part-2-using-markers-or-points-on-the-map-f8e9b5cae098

Answer (score 4):

Change

```
var marker = new ol.Feature({
    geometry: new ol.geometry.point(ol.proj.transform([16.9071388, 52.4901917], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')),
});
```

to

```
var marker = new ol.Feature({
    geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.transform([16.9071388, 52.4901917], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')),
});
```

and change the zoom from 12 to 11 in the view (otherwise, the point is here but outside of the initial view and you need to zoom out)

PS: Not sure where you got `ol.geometry.point` as it's never mentioned in the tutorial you referenced

Comment: I get "ol.geom.point is not a constructor" error in the console, then.

Comment: It's my answer... See this sample https://bl.ocks.org/ThomasG77/5e47a21c651be974cb688e8a8f967cca that show there are no issue in my answer. You may use a different version of OpenLayers (e.g 4.x) or a bundler?

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
 ol.geometry.point
```

to this

```
ol.geometry.Point
```

and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I know why it wasn't working. You have to type "ol.geom.Point" instead of "ol.geom.point" (uppercase).